# Conversión de tipo de dato en paso de variables en una url en PHP

Tags: php, web, conversión-de-tipos

Estimad@s, 
tengo el siguiente código y necesito mostrar estos datos en pantalla. Sucede que este array asociativo (ya intenté con otros y tampoco funciona) me muestra todos los datos como string y en la base las variables: Precio, Fecha y cod_art están en float, date e int respectivamente. Puedo cambiar en la base de datos para que todo sea string como una solución provisoria (estoy estudiando) pero me gustaría aprender hacer la conversión de tipos en este caso. Ya me fijé en el manual de php y con las funciones que pueden ayudar a convertir pero no funcionan.

```
<?php

try{
    $base = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=brenda_praktikum", "brenda", "hlRgJNJZzd6V7JPYgm68");

    //por si hay algún error en la conexión uso exception y errmode
    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $base->exec("set character set utf8");
```

$query="SELECT Sección, Artículo,  País_de_Origen, Precio, Fecha, cod_art FROM articulos where Sección= 'deporte'";

```
    $result=$base->prepare($query);

    $result->execute(array());



    $precio=['Precio'];
    $fecha=['Fecha'];
    $cod_art=['cod_art'];

    $precio= ['Precio'];



    while ($register=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            echo " Sección: ".$register['Sección'].
             " Artículo: ". $register['Artículo'].
             " País: ".$register['País_de_Origen'].
             " Precio: ".$register['Precio'].
             " Fecha: ".$register['Fecha'].
             " cod_art: ".$register['cod_art']. "<br>";


    }


    $result->closeCursor();

}catch (Exception $e){


    echo "Linea ". $e->getLine();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta  y el código que muestras tiene errores. Si quieres convertir una variable a un determinado tipo, sólo tienes que hacer algo así: `$precio= (float) $row[`Precio'];` suponiendo que los datos vienen de forma asociativa y los recuperas en `$row`. Si haces un `var_dump($precio);` verás el tipo y el valor. Supongo que leíste el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php) al respecto. Si esto no aclara tu duda, dinos con más claridad cuál es el problema y qué es lo que quieres convertir.

Comment: Qué parte exactamente no entendiste? Seguramente el codigo tiene errores, no estaría acá preguntando si fuera tan claro para mí :)

Comment: No se entiende qué es lo que quieres convertir. ¿Te refieres a las variables `$precio` y las otras variables? De entrada, la forma que usas para obtener los datos no es correcta y creo que ese es el error. En cuanto a la conversión, con declararla así ya la estás convirtiendo a ese tipo: `$variable = (float) $valor;` ¿Qué no entiendes exactamente?

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir un tipo, sólo tienes que poner el tipo entre paréntesis antes del valor. Por ejemplo:

```
$tipoFloat = (float) "10.77";
var_dump($tipoFloat);
```

***Salida***

```
float(10.77)
```

Aquí `$tipoFloat` será una variable del tipo `float` con el valor indicado en `$valor`.

Si en tu código quieres convertir alguno de los datos obtenidos de la base de datos a algún tipo, puedes hacer lo mismo.

Vamos a aplicarlo en el código, introduciendo además algunas mejoras:

- Puedes crear un array de opciones para pasarlo al constructor de la conexión, creándola así configurada como la quieres y no tener que estarle seteando más cosas luego. He agregado una opción que establece `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` a `FALSE`. Eso evita preparar las consultas emuladas, que en algunos escenarios pueden terminar en inyección de código.
- El charset lo puedes pasar usando punto y coma, después del nombre de la base de datos.
- No necesitas preparar la consulta para este caso, porque el dato que le pasas es fijo, por tanto no hay riesgo de inyección SQL, aquí puedes usar `query`.
- He quitado estas líneas `$precio=['Precio']` etc, porque no sé que hacían ahí, eso no hace nada.

Por ejemplo:

```
try{
    $options = array(
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                    );
    
    $base = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=brenda_praktikum;charset=utf8", "brenda", "hlRgJNJZzd6V7JPYgm68",$options);
    $query="SELECT Sección, Artículo, País_de_Origen, Precio, Fecha, cod_art FROM articulos where Sección= 'deporte'";
    $result=$base->query($query);
    while ($register=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        #Guardamos los datos en variables para que sea más clara la conversión de tipos
        $seccion=$register['Sección'];
        $articulo=$register['Artículo'];
        $pais=$register['País_de_Origen'];
        $precio=(float) $register['Precio'];   #Declarada del tipo float
        $fecha=$register['Fecha'];
        $cod_art=(float) $register['cod_art']; #Declarada del tipo float
        echo " Sección: $seccion Artículo: $articulo País: $pais Precio: $precio Fecha: $fecha cod_art: $cod_art <br />";
    }

    $result->closeCursor();

}catch (Exception $e){

    echo "Linea ". $e->getLine();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

### Recomendaciones

- No cometas el error de modificar tus tipos de datos en la base de datos por esto. El tipo de dato debe ajustarse a la realidad. Si un dato maneja números, tiene que ser numérico, no del tipo varchar.
- Evita nombrar tablas o columnas con palabras acentuadas o caracteres especiales. Esto te puede traer problemas en ciertos contextos.

Comment: Necesito imprimir los datos en un array, no pasarlos a float porque ya están guardados de esa forma en la base de datos, o en su caso date e int. Al momento de querer mostrar los datos de la tabla con un array los que tienen un tipo diferente a string no los muestra correctamente. El código que me agregaste no lo entiendo, mejor dejarlo así mismo, para no confundirme. Gracias

Comment: @BrendaYanelaConzi si quieres que te ayudemos tienes que ser clara en lo que preguntas. Lo que se entiende es que quieres convertilos a float. Si lo que deseas es pasarlos a un array solamente tienes que declarar el array antes del bucle `while` y luego dentro del bucle ir llenando el array. Por ejemplo: `$datos=array(); while ($register=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ $datos[]=$register; } //usar $datos` Ahí tendrías en `$datos` todas las filas en forma de array asociativo.